# Не десериализуется корректный JSON в параметр действия

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

На сервере есть контроллер, у которого есть следующий метод:

```
[HttpPost]
public bool Register([FromBody]SalesPoint salesPoint)
{
   ...
}
```

`SalesPoint` описывается так:

```
public class SalesPoint
{   
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<TerminalType, List<Terminal>> Terminals { get; set; } = new Dictionary<TerminalType, List<Terminal>>();
}

public enum TerminalType
{
    Type1 = 1,
    Type2 = 2
}

public class Terminal
{
    public TerminalType Type { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }   

}
```

Клиент формирует корректный JSON и отправляет его на сервер, но параметр `salesPoint` приходит как null.

При тесте через PostMan такой JSON (корректный) не воспринимается методом:

```
{
    "Name": "Test",
    "Terminals": [{
        "Key": 1,
        "Value": [{
            "Type": 1,
            "Code": "78-343002"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Но если выкинуть JSON словаря и отправить так:

```
{
    "Name": "Test"
}
```

То он нормально десериализуется. В чем проблема?

Comment: какой то странный у вас словарь в json

Comment: В показанном json откуда-то взялся массив в `Terminals` (квадратные скобки). А там должен быть сразу объект (фигурные скобки). Как вы получили этот json?

Comment: @tym32167, @Alexander Petrov, Действительно, Json оказался неправильным. С клиента запросы идут через RestSharp и тело запроса формируется через `AddJsonBody`.

Comment: @tym32167, Оформите как ответ по праву первого?)

Comment: не, я не успеваю это сделать сегодня, так что передаю эстафету @AlexanderPetrov )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В словаре ключ-значение маппятся в ключ-значение JSON'а. Правильно так:

```
{
  "Name": "Test",
  "Terminals": {
    "Type1": [
      {
        "Type": 1,
        "Code": "78-343002"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```